# How to build a project using libvirt java binding

Tags: java, maven, ant, installation, libvirt

it might be a stupid question but how do I set up an environment to develop a test application using libvirt?
do I have to set up ant or maven project or can I just copy java files to my src folder in eclipse ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse, you can build your classes and run your program in Eclipse without using Ant or Maven. In fact, Eclipse is usually completely ignorant of your Ant `build.xml` or your Maven `pom.xml` file. Eclipse uses its own build technology (although you can ask it to run your `pom.xml` or `build.xml`). ***However***, a pure Eclipse way of building a project means there is no way to build and run your project except with Eclipse. If you have a continuous integration system, or someone downloads your project and simply wants to build your jar or war file, there's no way they can do it.

Actually, not *entirely* true. You could write a shell script to compile your code via the `javac` commands and jar it up via the `jar` command. What Maven and Ant do is give you a framework to help build your application and remove system dependencies.

Ant has an advantage of flexibility. You can do things easily in Ant that are harder to do in Maven. The disadvantage is that Ant has the flexibility to do things in a really, really bad way. I almost always recommend for developers to use Maven for new projects. It forces them to write their project in a standard way, and eliminates the need to write Ant build scripts which most developers really can't do.

What if you don't know Maven, but know Ant? I still recommend that you use Maven and take this as an opportunity to learn Maven.